# Why does Tensorflow's sampled_softmax_loss force you to use a bias, when experts recommend no bias be used for Word2Vec?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

All the tensorflow implementations of Word2Vec that I have seen has a bias in the negative sampling softmax function, including on the official tensorflow website

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec#vector-representations-of-words

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                 biases=nce_biases,
                 labels=train_labels,
                 inputs=embed,
                 num_sampled=num_sampled,
                 num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

This is from Google's free Deep Learning course https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb

```
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=embed,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

However, from both Andrew Ng and Richard Socher's lectures, they do not include a bias in their negative sampling softmaxes.

Even where this idea originated, Mikolov states that:

> biases are not used in the neural network, as no significant
>   improvement of performance was observed - following the Occam's razor,
>   the solution is as simple as it needs to be.

Mikolov, T.: Statistical Language Models Based on Neural Networks, p. 29
http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/thesis.pdf

So why do the official tensorflow implementations have a bias, and why does there not seem to be an option to not include a bias in the sampled_softmax_loss function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exercise you link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/5_word2vec.ipynb) defines `softmax_biases` to be zeros:

```
softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
```

That is: they're not using any actual bias in their word2vec example.

The `sampled_softmax_loss()` function is generic and used for many neural-networks; its decision to require a `biases` argument is unrelated to what's best for one particular neural-network application (word2vec), and accommodates the word2vec case by allowing (as here) all zeros.

Comment: Do I also need to specify not the train the bias so they remain at zero?

Comment: I don't know; if you check the biases after training, have they been changed?

Comment: They did, so I had to explicitly tell it to only train the other variables.

Comment: Aha! Just curious, how do you specify to not train the biases?

Comment: optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost, var_list=[variable 1 you want to train, variable 2 you want to train, etc. ] )

Comment: Is it possible that training the biases results in better values (even though it's not typically done in other word2vec packages following the original paper), and that's why the Google Deep Learning example you cite leaves them that way? (It seems the comment there, just above the `minimize()` line, is calling attention to the fact all `Variable` values are optimized; might another way to freeze biases be to not wrap `tf.zeros()` result inside `tf.Variable()`?